# Puppeteer and Chromium launch without flags

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, chromium

I have the following code and trying to intercept one certain HTTP request. The issue I am facing is that when chromium is launched via `puppeteer` there are some flags which cause some the requests to not get the desired data. When I manually launch chromium everything works fine.
Using the example of tiktok

Opened by Puppeteer

Request

[image]

Response

[image]

Following are the details of the chromium and you can see the flags with its `.exe`

[image]

When I manually open the chromium the following comes up
The same request with this response

[image]

[image]

I have tried the following codes

```
//const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
//const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');
var currentCookies = null;

//const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ignoreDefaultArgs : true });    
//const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe' , ignoreDefaultArgs : true });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
```

I have achieved it by using normal chrome but I cannot use that on production as it runs with centos and CLI.

My question is how can we start chromium without any flags?? So all the operations are done normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ignoreDefaultArgs` option. This can be used as a boolean or as an array.

**Boolean example**
When `ignoreDefaultArgs` is set to true, puppeteer won't add any flags to the command line but the ones you set on the `args` option.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ignoreDefaultArgs: true, args: ['--mute-audio'] });
```

**Array example**
When you set an array, puppeteer will remove those flags from the default arguments.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ignoreDefaultArgs: ["-some-flag"] });
```

As the doc says, these are dangerous settings because we know that Puppeteer works using those flies. So I would try to see which specific flag is causing troubles.

Comment: Its giving syntax error, can you please specify the documentation for using the args as array?

Comment: Done @MuneebZulfiqar

Comment: I added all the flags still that request is null. Ive even tried running it on linux CLI with but not working